# Laravel apply sortBy to a related models collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using the below code:

```
$greatDeals = $greatDealsinitial->sortBy(function ($deal, $key) {
    return $deal->hotel->room[0]->price;
});
```

Here `room` is an array, I want to sort this collection by `price` in the `room` array.
But I can't use `return $row->hotel->room->price;`

So how can I sort this?

my collection :

```
[
{
"id": 2,
"hotel_id": 1,
"deal_code": "sfg",
"date": "2018-04-13 00:00:00",
"discount": 12,
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2018-04-13 11:21:18",
"updated_at": "2018-04-13 11:21:18",
"deleted_at": null,
"client_id": 1,
"hotel": {
"id": 1,
"name": "Aloft Dongguan Songshan Lake",
"address": "Dongguan, China, 511700",
"phone": "76982106666",
"country": "101",
"country_name": "India",
"state": "35",
"state_name": "Tamil Nadu",
"city": "3551",
"city_name": "Abiramam",
"area": null,
"pincode": "511700",
"nearest_airport": null,
"nearest_railway": null,
"star": null,
"check_in": null,
"check_out": null,
"lat": "22.929869",
"lng": "113.89232800000002",
"description": null,
"astatus": "1",
"status": "0",
"created_at": "2018-04-13 10:27:30",
"updated_at": "2018-04-13 10:27:48",
"client_id": 1,
"hotel_age": null,
"hotel_privilege": "asdf",
"departure": "sdaf",
"checkout_fee": "asdf",
"book_policy": "sadf",
"hotel_secured": null,
"hotel_pets": null,
"hotel_other": null,
"room": [
{
"id": 3,
"roomtype_id": 2,
"room_count": null,
"max_adult": 2,
"max_children": 1,
"capacity": 3,
"room_number": null,
"floor": null,
"number": null,
"name": null,
"city_name": "Abiramam",
"city": 3551,
"price": "200.00",
"extra_bed_price": null,
"astatus": "1",
"status": "0",
"created_at": "2018-04-13 12:37:11",
"updated_at": "2018-04-13 12:37:52",
"deleted_at": null,
"client_id": 1,
"hotel_id": 1
},
{
"id": 1,
"roomtype_id": 1,
"room_count": null,
"max_adult": 2,
"max_children": 1,
"capacity": 3,
"room_number": null,
"floor": null,
"number": null,
"name": null,
"city_name": "Abiramam",
"city": 3551,
"price": "435.00",
"extra_bed_price": null,
"astatus": "1",
"status": "0",
"created_at": "2018-04-13 10:33:24",
"updated_at": "2018-04-13 11:21:38",
"deleted_at": null,
"client_id": 1,
"hotel_id": 1
}
]
}
},
{
"id": 4,
"hotel_id": 2,
"deal_code": "ertgerf",
"date": "2018-04-13 00:00:00",
"discount": 1,
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2018-04-13 11:47:39",
"updated_at": "2018-04-13 11:53:45",
"deleted_at": null,
"client_id": 2,
"hotel": {
"id": 2,
"name": "Temperance Lane",
"address": "Temperance Ln, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia",
"phone": "9842814927",
"country": "14",
"country_name": "Austria",
"state": "281",
"state_name": "Carinthia",
"city": "6843",
"city_name": "Maria Rain",
"area": "test",
"pincode": "2000",
"nearest_airport": "demo",
"nearest_railway": "test",
"star": null,
"check_in": "09:30 AM",
"check_out": "04:30 PM",
"lat": "-33.86963590000001",
"lng": "151.20667979999996",
"description": "test description",
"astatus": "1",
"status": "0",
"created_at": "2018-04-13 10:43:16",
"updated_at": "2018-04-13 11:41:25",
"client_id": 2,
"hotel_age": null,
"hotel_privilege": "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest",
"departure": "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest",
"checkout_fee": "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest",
"book_policy": "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest",
"hotel_secured": null,
"hotel_pets": null,
"hotel_other": "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest",
"room": [
{
"id": 2,
"roomtype_id": 1,
"room_count": null,
"max_adult": 2,
"max_children": 3,
"capacity": 5,
"room_number": null,
"floor": null,
"number": null,
"name": null,
"city_name": "Maria Rain",
"city": 6843,
"price": "345.00",
"extra_bed_price": null,
"astatus": "1",
"status": "0",
"created_at": "2018-04-13 10:46:04",
"updated_at": "2018-04-13 10:47:05",
"deleted_at": null,
"client_id": 2,
"hotel_id": 2
}
]
}
}
]
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Which room price do you want to use for sorting?

Comment: one `hotel` having `many rooms`. so, `return $deal->hotel->room[0]->price;` here, i want to sort all rooms by price without giving `room[0]`

Comment: Do you want to sort the deals or the rooms?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, i want to sort rooms, based on its price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sorts the rooms of each hotel per price:

```php
$greatDealsinitial->each(function($deal) {
    $deal->hotel->setRelation('room', $deal->hotel->room->sortBy('price'));
});
```

Comment: when i give `dd($deal->hotel->setRelation('room', $deal->hotel->room->sortBy('price')));` it shows the result what i wanted. but i cant able to assign it in a variable, like this `$greatDeals = $greatDealsinitial->sortBy......`

Comment: if i assign like this,`$greatDeals = $greatDealsinitial->sortBy......`  then i cant see the sorted values.

Comment: Do you mean `$greatDeals = $greatDealsinitial->each...`?

Comment: Are the rooms not sorted if you run `dd($greatDealsinitial[0]->hotel->room);`?

Comment: noo, the rooms are not sorted, if run dd($greatDealsinitial[0]->hotel->room);

Comment: but when i give dd($deal->hotel->setRelation('room', $deal->hotel->room->sortBy('price'))); it sorts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168988/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-arun).

Comment: use `transform` with this answer if u want `hotel` also in that collection

Answer (score 0):

```
$greatDeals = $greatDealsinitial->hotel->room->sortBy('price') 

if this array looks 
 [
   ['price' => 0], 
   ['price' => 1], 
   ['price' => 3]
 ]
```